# How to launch an app with javascript?

Tags: javascript, facebook, html, facebook-graph-api, webview

I am developing an HTML5 game which uses Facebook sdk. This game is support the run in native mobile app which uses WebView. As you know, Facebook sdk doesn't work well on WebViews such as the login authentication. So what I want to do is when the user clicks "login to Facebook" in the app, then launch the browser and let the user login to Facebook. After the login, take the user back to the native app and refresh the page. Is it to do all these with javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use the FaceBook SDK for Javscript as you suspected. The basic code snippet that is provided here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/ will place a login button on your page (that your app would direct to).

There's plenty of guidance regarding the login flow on that page.